# How to populate a dropdownlist based on a selected value in another dropdownlist in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Populate a constituency dropdownlist based on a selected value of a county.

I am populating a constituency dropdownlist based on the value selected in the county dropdownlistlist. Where I will filter all constituencies that belong to a county in ASP.net core. The county dropdownlist is populating but the constituency dropdownlist is not populating.

```
 **Model Section**
    public string ConstituencyID { get; set; }
    public string Constituencyname { get; set; }
    public string CustNo { get; set; }
    public string ConnectedCusts { get; set; }
    public string CountyID { get; set; }
    public County county{ get; set; }



**Controller Section**
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetconstituencyList(string countyId)
        {
    var constituencylist = new SelectList(_context.Constituency.Where(c => 
    c.county.CountyID == countyId), "ConstituencyID", "Constituencyname");
    return Json(constituencylist);
        }

**View Section**

   <label asp-for="CountyID" class="control-label"></label>
   <select asp-for="CountyID" class="form-control" asp- 
   items="ViewBag.CountyID" id="countylist"> </select>
   <label asp-for="ConstituencyID" class="control-label"></label>
   <select asp-for="ConstituencyID" class="form-control"select 
   id="Constituencylist"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
        $("#Constituencylist").html(items);
    });


    $("#countylist").change(function () {
        var countyId = $("#countylist").val();
        var url = "/Schemes/GetconstituencyList";

        $.getJSON(url, { CountyID: countyId }, function (data) {
            var item = "";
            $("#Constituencylist").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, Constituency) {
                item += '<option value="' + Constituency.value + '">' + Constituency.text + '</option>'
            });
            $("#Constituencylist").html(item);
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `SelectList` object as JSON, and then you're attempting to iterate directly over this object. `SelectList`, itself, is not enumerable; it has an `Items` member, which holds the enumerable. In other words, you need to change your JS to:

```
$.each(data.items, function (i, Constituency) {
```

Or, just return the list directly from your action. There's no need to to wrap it in a `SelectList`, as that doesn't really do anything for you:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetconstituencyList(string countyId)
{
    var constituencylist = _context.Constituency.Where(c => c.county.CountyID == countyId).Select(c => new { value = c.ConstituencyID, text = c.Constituencyname });
    return Ok(constituencylist);
}
```

I also took the liberty of changing the return type to `IActionResult`, instead of `JsonResult`. It's a bad idea to return a `JsonResult`, or *any* specific result type for that matter, directly. Let ASP.NET Core decide the serialization based on the `Accept` header.

Comment: The county dropdownlist populates but the constituency dropdownlist does not. Kindly assist